# Can't figure out how to override method from super class

Tags: java, class, inheritance

This is for a class assignment. We are given this code:

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private int age;

public Person(String n, int a)
{
this.name = n;
this.age = a;
}
public String getName()
{
return name;
}

public int getAge()
{
return age;
}

public void setName(String n)
{
name = n;
}

public void setAge(int a)
{
age = a;
}

public void print( )
{
System.out.println("Name: " + name);
System.out.println("Age: " + age);
}
}
```

and we must override the print method in this class here which extends the Person class:

```
public class CollegeKid extends Person
{
private double gpa;


 public double getGPA()
{
 return gpa;
}

public void setGPA(double g)
{
  gpa = g;
}

public void print( )
{/* your code here */
  }
}
```

sorry about the formatting on the first code.

i tried writing

```
public void print(){
super.print();
SOP("Name " + name);
SOP("Age " + age);
SOP("GPA " + gpa);}
```

but that didn't work..

this is the compiltation error i get: compilation error (line 2, column 31) : name has private access in inheritanceI.Person
compilation error (line 3, column 30) : age has private access in inheritanceI.Person

Comment: Define "didn't work". What did it do, and what did you expect?

Comment: i expected it to be able to print out the name/age from the Person class

Comment: By default, any method in a subclass which has the same name *and* type of a method in the superclass overrides that method. I recomend you (optional but desirable) to add the `@Override` annotation to the subclass method. That said... What do you mean by 'didn't work`?

Answer (score 4):

To take advantage of the superclass functionality, you correctly call `super.print();`.  The `name` and `age` variables are `private` in `Person`.  But you don't have to print the name and age again; the call to the superclass method already takes care of that.  You only need one `System.out.println` statement for the GPA.

Answer (score 0):

```
CollegeKid kid = new CollegeKid()
kid.set...(...)
kid.print()
```